# why cannot read /dev/console after reboot AIX

Tags: console, aix

I use `< /dev/console` when running Micro-Focus cobol programs in background cron jobs instead of `< /dev/null` because then we don't get an warning about the input file not supporting ioctl. The warning about the input file not supporting `ioctl` means that the script is not able to differentiate between this and a real error as the program returns the same value.

Usually (on many different AIX servers) I set up these jobs to run as root because other users do not have permissions to read `/dev/console`.

Over several years, I've had several problems that I just don't understand, and searching the internet for many hours hasn't helped. E.g.

1. a server changed, for no apparent reason, from where only root could use `< /dev/console` to where only a non-root user could use `< /dev/console`
2. a server where a non-root user was able to use `< /dev/console` changed after reboot so that only root could use `< /dev/console`

The 2nd example is my most recent case.
`lscons` shows the console is assigned to `/dev/tty0` and you can login on `/dev/tty0` fine.
I don't think anyone has used `swcons` or `chcons` to reassign the console before the reboot.

I've tried changing permissions on `/dev/console` & `/dev/tty0` to `666` but still only root can do, without error:

```
echo TEST < /dev/console
```

Does anybody understand what is happening or know how to change it so non-root users can read `/dev/console` ?

Any suggestions for another device that supports `ioctl` and could be used as a dummy stdin by non-root users?

(I suspect that the cobol program only opens stdin but doesn't actually read it when in the background).

Permissions now:
    crw-rw-rw-   1 root     system     4,  0 Aug 20 1999  /dev/console
    crw-rw-rw-   1 root     system    16,  0 Aug 09 13:39 /dev/tty0

Before I did: `chmod 666` :
    crw--w--w-   1 root     system     4,  0 Aug 20 1999  /dev/console
    crw-------   1 root     system    16,  0 Aug 09 13:39 /dev/tty0

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/dev/console` file?

Comment: Hi Drav, I've added permissions to original question.